# How to make an app similar to Pulse News Reader for Android

Tags: android

> http://androidapt.wordpress.com/2010/11/19/pulse-news-reader-an-android-app-that-kicks-rss/

Gallery inside ListView it's clear, but:

1. What is the technology that allows you to show a ScrollView under opening ListView?
2. How to make gallery and top bar move down by touching screen inside opened Scrollview?

I don't need the direct code, just show me where to lurk for this info.

[image]

I though that it uses [SlideDrawer](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/DrawerDemo), but it reacts only on touches, then i think it is something similar to [SlidingPanel](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Animation/SlidingPanel)

Comment: That is not a `Gallery` widget, AFAICT. My guess is a `LinearLayout` in a `HorizontalScrollView`. I am impressed that it works -- I wonder how much headache was involved. In terms of your questions, I have no idea what you are talking about and how they relate to the video.

Comment: No, it's GalleryView, i'm sure - It's work as Gallery View which was placd in every row of ListView. See video at 0:17. Or just install app and you will see. I know that You are great expert, and i was study by your books and app examples, but I'm sure that it Gallery inside ListView.

Comment: I'm working on an item that works similarly to this and trying to figure out the right combination of building blocks. Whether or not this is a "Gallery" I'm not sure, but a view that worked similarly would need to have the following: a row of views evenly divided to the layout width, snap to boundaries when a fling stops, unlike a  native ScrollView, a data adapter approach to managing memory and allows both dragging/flinging and clicking without conflict. I've worked around all of them except the fling/click conflict - have you guys managed put this all together?

Comment: Did you find out if it is a GalleryView? Or just a scroll view with special features?

Comment: I found that it was a SCrollView with LInearLayout inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accept Mark's answer as right way to made it.

> That is not a Gallery widget, AFAICT. My guess is a LinearLayout in a HorizontalScrollView. I am impressed that it works -- I wonder how much headache was involved. In terms of your questions, I have no idea what you are talking about and how they relate to the video

Answer (score 0):

It is a gallery with left margin adjusted.

Comment: NO, it's not a Gallery, have You seen it? The behaviour is totally different. Also i have seen the layout of this app - there are LinearLayout.
Also please view comment from Mark, he know what to say :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Mark, We have reengineered the pulse app, It is the gallery with its left margin adjusted.
and the center locking on gallery item click is also overridden.

Comment: would you mind sharing a simple example on how you have done it?